# How to Suppress Data IF user click on print button for the first time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm beginner with Crystal Reports.

Referring to the image below...

[image]

..., how can I suppress the data if the user prints for the first time?

Can I use `printstate(OntheFirstTime)`? If I can, how to use it?

Comment: Pass a parameter to your report indicating whether it is a reprint or not. Then set the Suppress value of the object you want to hide based on the parameter's value

Comment: Can you show the example?

Comment: Corrective Action:
1)In Crystal Report, right-click and select Format Object.

2)Search for "Suppress Embedded Field Blank Lines" checkbox and tick on it.

3)Click Ok.

4)Save the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrective Action:

1. In Crystal Report, right-click and select Format Object.
2. Search for "Suppress Embedded Field Blank Lines" checkbox and tick on it.
3. Click Ok.
4. Save the changes.

Thanks

Comment: I guess there is no experts know about it. Only exist the experts that only know editing "number" in my answer. LOL :)